# Clear text editline

Tags: python

I need help with an editline. I am trying to set a text inside of editline and when you press click on that text inside of editline, the text will clear and you can write.
Can someone help me with that? I understand the error but I don't know how to do it differently.

> BindObject - :'EditLine' object has
>   no attribute 'SetEvent'

```
self.name = self.GetChild("name")

def LoadName(self):
    self.name.SetText("Your Name Here")

            {
                "name" : "naming", 
                "type" : "expanded_image",
                "style" : ("attach",),

                "x" : 12, 
                "y" : 78, 

                "image" : "d:/ymir work/ui/img.tga",

                "children" :
                (
                    {
                        "name" : "name",
                        "type" : "editline",

                        "x" : 11,
                        "y" : 28,

                        "width" : 129,
                        "height" : 16,

                        "input_limit" : 20,

                        #"text" : uiScriptLocale.WHISPER_NAME,
                    },
                ),
            },
```

Comment: question is very unclear. Add some code and also full traceback

Comment: Yeap i was doing that.

Comment: Question still extremely unclear, try to also correct the phrasing.

Comment: When you press that text in the window the text will clear. http://prntscr.com/g3zav4